# Should I use a function or a parameter in my report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, reporting-services

SSRS gives you the ability to use [parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337432%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

[image]

Alternatively you can actually [write your own function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx) within the RDL file:

**I am wondering in what situation would one use the capabilities of a function rather than a parameter, since you can implement logic in both>?**

For example, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx) has chosen to code this:

```
Public Function ChangeWord(ByVal s As String) As String
   Dim strBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder(s)
   If s.Contains("Bike") Then
      strBuilder.Replace("Bike", "Bicycle")
      Return strBuilder.ToString()
      Else : Return s
   End If
End Function
```

I can just as well create an [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) statement within a parameter and do the same.

Comment: It's a question about preferences... ;)

Comment: well, that is my question indeed, is it about preferences, or is there a standard practice of when to use what?

Comment: for example, i have been using parameters for years and just today i've learned that i can actually write functions!

Comment: I prefer to use custom function. For me, it's more flexible ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been working with SSRS for years and never used a function(vba). I think it is better to use parameters. My suggestion is based on the following reasons....

1. SSRS is a tool designed to present data. Data manipulation is best handled on sql server.
2. Using parameters also allow you to do data manipulation closer to data source. Only bring data that is actually needed by the report. Bringing data to SSRS and then filtering out using functions will obviously involve unnecessary data processing.
3. Code maintenance is easier when you have all the code in one place. (stored procedures in sql server, functions in ssrs reports).
4. why redo the work that has already been taken care for you. The example of function you have shown, can easily be replaced by using the sql-server's built-in replace function (again sql-server will handle this much better and quicker than ssrs).

and the list goes on.... as they say `keep it simple`, try to make full use of the built-in functionality of sql server and ssrs and avoid writing unnecessary code.

Comment: thank you very much. you gave me lots of clarity. sometimes it works out that you don't have access to sql server. for example with crm online, you can only query through web services, which is very limiting, so you are forced to do lots of processing on the front end

Comment: @Yuck yup when you are working with a source with limited access then obviously it makes sense to make use of these functions but since your question was tagged with sql server, I wouldnt do it with sql-server but yes maybe with a data source like crm-online :)